# .net Azure Cosmos SDK aggregate functions

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

No matter what I try, I cannot get `Max()`, `MaxAsync()` or a direct SQL Query get to work in Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos 3.38.1.

If I run the following statement in the **Cosmos DB Emulator**

```
SELECT MAX(f.preisEuro) AS maxWert, MIN(f.preisEuro) AS minWert FROM fahrzeuge f
```

I get the expected result

```json
[
    {
        "maxWert": 5000000,
        "minWert": 1273
    }
]
```

Neither this code works:

```cs
var query = new QueryDefinition(
    "SELECT max(f.preisEuro) as maxWert, min(f.preisEuro) as minWert FROM fahrzeuge f");

 using var setIterator = container.GetItemQueryIterator<dynamic>(
     query
     ,requestOptions: new QueryRequestOptions()
     {
         // PartitionKey = new PartitionKey(MagicValues.PartionKeyValue),
         MaxConcurrency = 1,
         // MaxItemCount = 1,
     }
 );
 var results = new List<dynamic>();
 while (setIterator.HasMoreResults)
 {
     var response = await setIterator.ReadNextAsync();
     Console.WriteLine($"Response: {response.StatusCode}");
     results.AddRange(response);
 }
```

Nor does this code:

```cs
var minPreis = await  container.GetItemLinqQueryable<Fahrzeug>()
            .Select(f => f.PreisEuro).MinAsync();
```

I tried upper/lowercasing of the variable names and min() and max() keywords in the SQL but all results I get in return are empty curly braces as Json or 0 for `MinAsync()` and `MaxAsync()`

I know that one solution would be to read the whole contaienr and calculate the values in a loop but if there are `MinAsync()`, `MaxAsync()` functions in  `Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Linq.CosmosLinqExtensions`

## Update / Solution

> the underlying issue was that I had used a wrong container(name). Cosmos doesn't throw any error if that container exists but simply returns 0 for Min/Max or an empty result when using the SQL statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> .net Azure Cosmos SDK aggregate functions

`Aggregate functions` worked successfully in both `QueryDefinition` method and `LINQ` method. Also both the codes uses `Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos 3.38.1` version. `LINQ` method uses `Min()` and `Mix()`  as you can see in the code below. Install `Newtonsoft.Json` package in the `LINQ` code.

While executing query in Azure Cosmos DB Emulator by taking some sample data:

```sql
SELECT  MAX(f.preisEuro) AS maxWert, MIN(f.preisEuro) AS minWert FROM fahrzeuge f
```

**Output:**

```js
[
    {
        "maxWert": 50000,
        "minWert": 25000
    }
]
```

Code with **QueryDefinition** method:

```cs
static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var cosmosClient = new CosmosClient(EndpointUri, PrimaryKey);
        var database = cosmosClient.GetDatabase(DatabaseId);
        var container = database.GetContainer(ContainerId);

        var query = new QueryDefinition("SELECT max(f.preisEuro) AS maxWert, min(f.preisEuro) AS minWert FROM fahrzeuge f");
        var resultSet = container.GetItemQueryIterator<dynamic>(query);

        while (resultSet.HasMoreResults)
        {
            var response = await resultSet.ReadNextAsync();
            foreach (var item in response)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Max Value: {item["maxWert"]}, Min Value: {item["minWert"]}");
            }
        }
    }
```

**Output:**

```js
Max Value: 50000, Min Value: 25000
```

Code with **LINQ** method:

```cs
public class Car
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("marke")]
    public string Marke { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("preisEuro")]
    public double PreisEuro { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    private const string EndpointUrl = "*****";
    private const string PrimaryKey = "******";
    private const string DatabaseId = "NewDb";
    private const string ContainerId = "newCont";

    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var client = new CosmosClient(EndpointUrl, PrimaryKey))
        {
            var database = client.GetDatabase(DatabaseId);
            var container = database.GetContainer(ContainerId);

            var query = container.GetItemLinqQueryable<Car>(true);

            var minPreis = query.Min(car => car.PreisEuro);
            var maxPreis = query.Max(car => car.PreisEuro);

            Console.WriteLine($"Minimum preisEuro: {minPreis}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Maximum preisEuro: {maxPreis}");
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```js
Minimum preisEuro: 25000
Maximum preisEuro: 50000
```

Comment: thanks for looking into this. I just realized that i had the wrong Container name in .net. I will delete this question soon and upvote another of your answers as a sign of gratitude. it works correctly as you say

Comment: @Jan - excellent that you figured out it was a container-name mistake. That would be a good comment to make under the question. Also... no need to promise votes or offer thanks - just vote as you see fit.